# Aurelia skeleton-typescript-webpack does not start on windows

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to run the skeleton-typescript-webpack  from [github](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation) on windows 7 but after the (successful) npm install the npm start give me the following error

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/library/fn/object/get-own-property-names'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive\ausites\stw\node_modules\@easy-webpack\config-aurelia\node_modules\aurelia-webpack-plugin\node_modules\babel-runtime\core-js\object\get-own-property-names.js:1:93)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:dev"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.0 server:dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --profile --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Any idea on how to resolve this.

Comment: what version of node and npm do you have?

Comment: EDIT: I see you're running the latest node and npm versions. this is a hard one. have you tried uninstalling all node modules and double checking the referenced versions in your package.json?

Comment: I'm getting this same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the path length being too long. In windows there seems to be a limit of 256 characters.

I moved it up in the file system tree to get a short path and it worked. 
The Aurealia doc also recommends to use Git bash or Git Shell, this may also solve the issue, but I have not tried this.

Comment: install nodejs 6; it dedups automatically